# c++ using declaration keyword usage seen in the examples of Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, using-directives

i have noticed that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    ....
}
```

uses **using `boost::asio::ip::tcp`** and not **using namespace** where `tcp` is a class.
can some one tell me whats the benefit of writing it in such a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't populate the global namespace with all the contents of `namespace boost::asio::ip`.

You only use what you need. Take the following example:

```
namespace A
{
   void foo() {}
   void goo() {}
}

namespace B
{
   void foo() {}
   void goo() {}
}
```

If you were to do

```
using namespace A;
using namespace B;
```

You would get an ambiguity when trying to call the methods.

But you can say something like:

```
using A::foo;
using B::goo;
```

and the ambiguity will be gone.

Of course, the safest way to do it is not using `using` at all and fully qualify the names on each use.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **using declaration** (as opposed to **using directive**.

Typing `boost::asio::ip::tcp;` will give you a "shortcut" to the `tcp` class, but not to the rest of the `boost::asio::ip` namespace.

Comment: Ah well, see Luchian's more detailed explanation above.. ;)